# How to change the value of a Slider programmatically? (LibGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx, slider, desktop-application

I think I am missing something obvious, but I can't seem to change the value of a Slider (Scene2D.ui) programmatically.
The reason that I want to do this is because I have a character that you can customize with the sliders but I want to have some preset characters that you can use as a starting point for customization.

What I have so far is something like this:

`(ChangeListener)(slider.getListeners().get(0))` but I cannot call the `changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor)` method that is called when the slider is changed.

Comment: You need to wrap the cast: `((ChangeListener) slider.getListeners().get(0)).change`

Comment: Have you tried calling progressBar.setValue?

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ProgressBar.html#setValue-float-

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setValue(float value)` method of `Slider` to change value of slider programmatically.

```
public class GdxTest extends ApplicationAdapter {

    Stage stage;
    Slider slider;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        stage=new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        Skin skin=new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/glassy-ui.json"));

        Table table=new Table();
        table.setFillParent(true);

        stage.addActor(table);
        table.add(slider=new Slider(0,100,1,false,skin));

        slider.setValue(50);   // value changed by 50%
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
slider.setAnimateDuration(0.3f);
```